# Second order, homogeneous, linear boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I could not solve differential equation.

$$x^{"}- 3x^{'} -9 e^{6t} x = 0   , x(0)=0  , x(1)=1  $$
that $e^{6t} = \exp(6t)$

please help me.

Comment: Do you know how to use series to solve a differential equation? Take a look at this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/HOSeries.aspx

Comment: yes, but this equation have an exponential finction.

Answer (score 0):

Make the change $y = e^{3t} $ and then the original equation is transformed to

$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{y}^{2}}}x \left( y \right) -x \left( y \right) =0$$

solving this equation and applying the boundary conditions we obtain

$$x \left( t \right) =-{\frac { \left( {{\rm e}^{2}}+1 \right) {{\rm e}^
{{{\rm e}^{3}}}}\sinh \left( {{\rm e}^{3\,t}} \right) }{-{{\rm e}^{2\,
{{\rm e}^{3}}}}+{{\rm e}^{2}}}}+{\frac { \left( {{\rm e}^{2}}-1
 \right) {{\rm e}^{{{\rm e}^{3}}}}\cosh \left( {{\rm e}^{3\,t}}
 \right) }{-{{\rm e}^{2\,{{\rm e}^{3}}}}+{{\rm e}^{2}}}}
$$